# How to segregate a object according to an id?

Tags: javascript

how to create the object group based on id and and unpack the array.

I tried doing it with 2 for loops but im getting duplicate objects, even if i remove duplicate objects, same pname is coming for 2 ids.

```
 this.entityChecked = list.map(a => a.e_id);    
        const checkedaccessDetails = list.map(a => a.details);
                const productCampMerged = [].concat.apply([], checkedaccessDetails);
                const tpcode = productCampMerged.map(a => a.tp_code);
                this.campaignChecked = [].concat.apply([], tpcode);    
            for (let j = 0; j < this.entityChecked.length; j++) {
                      for (let i = 0; i < this.campaignChecked.length; i++) {
                        this.campaignArr.push({ pid: this.entityChecked[j], pcode: productCampMerged[0].pcode, pname: this.campaignChecked[i] })
                      }
                    }
```

response from api

```
{
   "pid":"1",
   "details":[
      {
         "pcode":"van",
         "pname":["mobile","hphone"]
      }
   ]
},
{
   "pid":"2",
   "details":[
      {
         "pcode":"car",
         "pname":["wphone","email"]
      }
   ]
},
{
   "pid":"3",
   "details":[
      {
         "pcode":"bus",
         "pname":["sms"]
      }
   ]
}
```

expexted output:

```
[
   {"pid":"1","pcode":"van","pname":"mobile"},
   {"pid":"1","pcode":"van","pname":"hphone"},
   {"pid":"2","pcode":"car","pname":"wphone"},
   {"pid":"2","pcode":"car","pname":"email"},
   {"pid":"4","pcode":"bus","pname":"sms"}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution.

```js
let a = [
  {
    pid: "1",
    details: [
      {
        pcode: "van",
        pname: ["mobile", "hphone"]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    pid: "2",
    details: [
      {
        pcode: "car",
        pname: ["wphone", "email"]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    pid: "3",
    details: [
      {
        pcode: "bus",
        pname: ["sms"]
      }
    ]
  }
];

let b = [];

a.map(item => {
  item.details.map(detail => {
    detail.pname.map(name => {
      b.push({
        pid: item.pid,
        pcode: detail.pcode,
        pname: name
      });
    });
  });
});

console.log(b);
```